# Adjusting height of Today App Extension

Tags: user-interface, autolayout, today-extension

I have a Today Widget which displaying the upcoming train departures based on a pair of stations chosen in the main application.  Given that the departure times changes with time, I have an API call in `viewWillAppear` fetching the new times and repopulating the cells of a tableView.

Currently, the widget starts off with a height of what looks like 150-200 points in height.  My updating logic attempts to set the `preferredContent` height but this doesn't work.  I have the tableView constrained to the top/bottom layout guides.  I have tried resetting the tableView's frame height to the main view after telling it a new preferredContent.

Presumably, the callback of my network happens after viewWillAppear, so I invoke `layoutIfNeeded` to trigger `viewDidLayoutSubviews` where I reload the tableview.

None of this gets me what I want to see.  A tableview populated by the departure times which is `N times the height of a cell` where N is the number of departure times most recently fetched by my API call.

What am I missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## EDIT:

This is the relevant code where I attempt to re-height the extension.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
 
      dao.fetchTrips { (trips) in
        
         self.tripsDataSource.dataStore = trips
 
         let numTrips = trips?.count
         let rowHeight = 44 // static
         let h = numTrips! * rowHeight
         
         self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: h)
 
         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  
      }
      
   }
   
   

   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
```

I have noticed `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is not called after `layoutIfNeeded` is invoked in the completion handler.  Although that may not be the issue, as the app-extension main view does not change after setting a new `preferredContentSize`.

Comment: Could you show your code? A table view cannot size the widget from the inside out using constraints, so you _must_ use `preferredContentSize`. Can you should how you are doing that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Few minutes ago I solved it. The default view of widget doesn't show the max height. You need to press show more , next to App title.

Remove your code and just add this to your widget class and on else branch set the height what you want. This will call when you hit show less/ show more.

```
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
    func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize){
        if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.compact) {
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: maxSize.height);
        }
        else {
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: self.tableView.contentSize.height);
        }
    }
```

Edited: My code:

```
import UIKit
import NotificationCenter

let groupappname = "group.***.***"


class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController , NCWidgetProviding,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var isEmptyData = true
    var array = NSMutableArray()
    var defaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: groupappname)!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *) {
            self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = NCWidgetDisplayMode.expanded
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }


        registerObserver()
        refreshData()

    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        removeObserver()
    }

    func refreshData(){

        self.preferredContentSize = (self.collectionView?.contentSize)!
        #somecode
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    func refreshData_NoData(){
        self.preferredContentSize = (self.collectionView?.contentSize)!
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
    func widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler: @escaping (NCUpdateResult) -> Void) {
        print("widgetperformupdate")
        completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.newData)
    }
    @available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
    func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize){
        if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.compact) {
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: maxSize.height)
        }
        else {
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: (self.collectionView?.contentSize.height)!)
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items

        return array.count
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        #somecode
        self.preferredContentSize = collectionView.contentSize

        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: I added this to my extension and `(activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.compact)` is the only conditional that is executed, and even when it is, the preferredContentSize height I give it has no effect.

Comment: @user5797668 firstly do not forget to add super.viewWillAppear(animated) to viewwillappear function and super.viewDidLayoutSubviews(). I have 
        self.preferredContentSize = collectionView.contentSize in cellforitem. So if you have tableview or collectionview try to set self.preferredContentSize there. Lets try that

Comment: Heres the thing.  preferredContentSize never has an effect, it seems.  Even if I comment out ALL code.  And simply set height to 600 in viewDidLoad, the extension stays at 100-200points hight whatever it is now.

Comment: Add this inside viewdidload function         `if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *) {
            self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = NCWidgetDisplayMode.expanded
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }`

Comment: This isn't working either.  Could you  perhaps direct me to the documentation you original used to handle widget sizing.

Comment: I will send you my all code 6 hours later. There is time difference. (Gmt+3)

Comment: @user5797668 I add my code to my answer. Please look. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I was facing the same issue, for some strange reason setting `widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode` in `viewDidLoad()` didn't work as `self.extensionContext` was coming as `nil`. Moving the code to `viewDidAppear()` did the trick.